# Can I use SharePoint Online user in SharePoint OnPremise?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a requirement to make a Single Sign-On between the SharePoint Online and SharePoint on-Premise. I have read some articles on google which shows the process of synching the On-Premise users to the SharePoint online and then use that user to login in to the SharePOint Online site.

But My Scenario is reverse, I want to sync the SharePoint online user into the SharePoint On-Premise. So that the user which is created in SharePoint Online sync in the Sharepoint On-premise and , that user can use the SharePoint On Premise Site.

Is it possible with the same process of Synch for the SharePoint Online and SharePoint On Premise? is it work reverse way too? or I need to do some other thing for that ?

Please advise?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft supports different types of SharePoint Server 2013 hybrid environments and the hybrid solutions. You can refer below link for the supported Hybrid Topology by SharePoint:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn607308.aspx

Using **SharePoint Hybrid One-way Inbound Topology**, you can setup connection requests from SharePoint Online to SharePoint On-Premise, But again it has some limitation and you can use this for below scenario only:

- Inbound hybrid search (displaying search results from SharePoint Server 2013 in Office 365)
- Hybrid Business Connectivity Services
- Hybrid Duet Enterprise Online for Microsoft SharePoint and SAP

If you want to use SharePoint Online user as a logon credential for SharePoint On-Premise, then it's not supported yet.

For Inbound topology you will have to setup reverse proxy device, which will authenticate SharePoint Online requests to SharePoint On-Premise, but again for the authentication it uses federated users (Intranet User). You can refer to below links to get more familiar with concept and configuration of Hybrid Technology:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn607304.aspx
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn607311.aspx#syncuserprofiles
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn607316.aspx

Hope these details will help you to understand that we can not use SharePoint Online user in SharePoint On-Premise environment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have already gone throught this links and it does not fit in my requirements.